# C6385 Reading invalid data from 'this->users'; the readable size is '(size_t)*32+8 bytes, but '64' bytes may be read

Tags: c++

So I am building my application on C++ and I have created this class. As soon as I make a new buffer for dynamic memory (i am using size and capacity) I get this error

"C6385 Reading invalid data from 'this->users'; the readable size is '(size_t)*32+8 bytes, but '64' bytes may be read."

I do not know what is causing it, I tried changing size and capacity from int to size_t and backwards but it does not work. 
IT SAYS IT ON LINE - this->users[i] = other.users[i];
Please help

```
SocialNetwork::SocialNetwork()
{
    this->size = 0;
    this->capacity = 42;
    this->users = new User[this->capacity];
}

void SocialNetwork::copy(const SocialNetwork& other)
{
    this->size = other.size;
    this->capacity = other.capacity;
    this->users = new User[this->capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
    {
        this->users[i] = other.users[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to check that size is less than or equal to capacity. The compiler does not know that. You allocate for `this->capacity` but loop on `this->size`

Comment: suggest using `vector<User>` instead of raw pointers and new. Then you avoid all these problems,  and the built-in assignment operator works instead of writing your own  (and it is unclear why you called it `copy` instead of `operator=`)

Comment: in addition, by doing `this->users = new User[this->capacity];` you lost `this->users` pointer and you will have a `memory leaks`